# Holding a push button for 3 second in a for loop

Tags: algorithm, button, arduino

I have a button that basically has two functions. The aim is:

- First push will blink a LED 15 times.
- If someone holds the button longer than 3 seconds while the LED is blinking, it should stop and go back to the initial.

So I checked the Arduino's hold a button page and came up with this code. The problem is that I can not properly stop the blinking. The line `Serial.println("DONE!!");` never works.
Where should I check if the button is held or not and should I use interrupt to end the for loop?

Here is my code:

```cpp
int inPin = 2;  // the pin number for input (for me a push button)
int ledPin = 9;
int current;         // Current state of the button
// (LOW is pressed b/c I'm using the pullup resistors)
long millis_held;    // How long the button was held (milliseconds)
long secs_held;      // How long the button was held (seconds)
long prev_secs_held; // How long the button was held in the previous check
byte previous = LOW;
unsigned long firstTime; // how long since the button was first pressed
long millis_held2;    // How long the button was held (milliseconds)
long secs_held2;      // How long the button was held (seconds)
long prev_secs_held2; // How long the button was held in the previous check
byte previous2 = LOW;
unsigned long firstTime2; // how long since the button was first pressed

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600); // Use serial for debugging
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(inPin, INPUT); // Turn on 20k pullup resistors to simplify switch input
}

void loop() {
  current = digitalRead(inPin);
  // if the button state changes to pressed, remember the start time
  if (current == HIGH && previous == LOW && (millis() - firstTime) > 200) {
    firstTime = millis();
  }
  millis_held = (millis() - firstTime);
  secs_held = millis_held / 1000;
  // This if statement is a basic debouncing tool, the button must be pushed for at least
  // 100 milliseconds in a row for it to be considered as a push.
  if (millis_held > 50) {
    // check if the button was released since we last checked
    if (current == LOW && previous == HIGH) {
      // HERE YOU WOULD ADD VARIOUS ACTIONS AND TIMES FOR YOUR OWN CODE
      // ===============================================================================

      //////////////////////////////////////////////////////// Button pressed Blink 15 times.
      if (secs_held <= 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
          ledblink(1, 750, ledPin);
          current = digitalRead(inPin);
          if (current == HIGH && previous == LOW && (millis() - firstTime2) > 200) {
            firstTime2 = millis();
          }
          millis_held2 = (millis() - firstTime2);
          secs_held2 = millis_held2 / 1000;
          if (millis_held2 > 50) {
            Serial.print("previousA  ");
            Serial.print(previous);
            Serial.print(" currentA  ");
            Serial.println(current);
            current = digitalRead(inPin);
            if (current == HIGH && previous2 == HIGH) {
              Serial.println("ALMOST! ");
              Serial.println(secs_held2);
              if (secs_held2 >= 2 && secs_held2 < 6) {
                Serial.println("DONE!!");
              }
            }
          }
          previous2 = current;
          prev_secs_held2 = secs_held2;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  previous = current;
  prev_secs_held = secs_held;
}

void ledblink(int times, int lengthms, int pinnum) {
  for (int x = 0; x < times; x++) {
    digitalWrite(pinnum, HIGH);
    delay (lengthms);
    digitalWrite(pinnum, LOW);
    delay(lengthms);
  }
}
```

Comment: delay() makes everything harder for continuous polling of inputs.  It is also good practice to try to only poll your inputs at one point in code.

Comment: You will need to use a "break();" statement when you have noticed that the button has been held too long.  That will allow you to exit your for loop immediately. Probably add it on a line below "Serial.println("DONE!!");" if I understand your code correctly.

Comment: The problem in my code is line "Serial.println("DONE!!");" never works

Comment: your implementation of secs_held2 is unnecessary.  You can just use the original secs_held and watch its timer in order to determine the long press.  Only check the input to see that the press has ended.

Answer (score 0):

This is how it would be done without using `delay()`:

```cpp
int inPin = 2;
int ledPin = 9;

long pressTimer;

long blinkTimer;
long blinkHalfDelay = 500; //milliseconds
int blinkCount = 0;
int blinkLimit = 15;
bool blinkFlag = false;
bool blinkLatch = true;


bool currentBtnState = false;
bool lastBtnState = false;

void setup() {
}

void loop() {
    lastBtnState = currentBtnState;
    currentBtnState = digitalRead(inPin);

    //on rising edge, start timers
    if(currentBtnState==true && lastBtnState==false)
    {
        pressTimer = millis();
    }

    //debounce activation
    if(currentBtnState==true && !blinkFlag && millis()-pressTimer > 50)
    {
        blinkTimer = millis();
        blinkCount = 0;
        blinkLatch = true;
        blinkFlag = true;

        //functional execution would go here
    }

    if(currentBtnState = false || (millis()-pressTimer>3000 && currentBtnState == true))
    {
        blinkCount=blinkLimit;
        blinkLatch = false;
    }

    if(blinkFlag == true)
    {
        if(millis()-blinkTimer > blinkHalfDelay)
        {
            blinkTimer = millis();
            if(blinkLatch)
            {
                digitalWrite(pinnum, HIGH);
            }
            else
            {
                digitalWrite(pinnum, LOW);
                blinkCount+=1;
            }
        }
        if(blinkCount>blinkLimit)
        {
            blinkFlag = false;
            digitalWrite(pinnum, LOW);
        }
    }
}
```

ps: sorry for not correcting your code directly, but it was kinda hard to read...

Comment: to be more specific, I looked here to learn how to use hold a button in arduino: https://playground.arduino.cc/Code/HoldButton. In this page (If you could have a look there), It works perfectly But what I couldnt success the part I want that it should end blinking while I hold the button for longer than 3 sec. in the for loop. I tried to check all process like the way it shown in the page in for loop. But i didn't help